# Encrypt/decrypt image with AES256 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to encrypt and decrypt an image with AES256. I'm working on the program below, which encrypts plaintext.

AES is an algorithm that has fixed length input in 128 bit. It work in four different steps every round; AES256 has 14 rounds, as the program shows for a different kind of this algorithm.

I'm looking to adapt the main program for any image that surely will have a length larger than 128bit. Should I divide it into many blocks that have the same size, or do you have other suggestions?

```
function [output] = aes(s, oper, mode, input, iv, sbit)
% AES Encrypt/decrypt array of bytes by AES.
% output = aes(s, oper, mode, input, iv, sbit)
% Encrypt/decrypt array of bytes by AES-128, AES-192, AES-256.
% All NIST SP800-38A cipher modes supported (e.g. ECB, CBC, OFB, CFB, CTR).
% Usage example:    out = aesdecrypt(s, 'dec', 'ecb', data)
% s:                AES structure (generated by aesinit)
% oper:             operation:
%                   'e', 'enc', 'encrypt', 'E',... = encrypt
%                   'd', 'dec', 'decrypt', 'D',... = decrypt
% mode:             operation mode
%                   'ecb' = Electronic Codebook Mode
%                   'cbc' = Cipher Block Chaining Mode
%                   'cfb' = Cipher Feedback Mode
%                   'ofb' = Output Feedback Mode
%                   'ctr' = Counter Mode
%                   For counter mode you need external AES_GET_COUNTER()
%                   counter function.
% input:            plaintext/ciphertext byte-vector with length
%                   multiple of 16
% iv:               initialize vector - some modes need it
%                   ending initialize vector is stored in s.iv, so you
%                   can use aes() repetitively to encode/decode
%                   large vector:
%                   out = aes(s, 'enc', 'cbc', input1, iv);
%                   out = [out aes(s, 'enc', 'cbc', input1, s.iv)];
%                   ...
% sbit:             bit-width parameter for CFB mode
% output:           ciphertext/plaintext byte-vector
%
% See
% Morris Dworkin, Recommendation for Block Cipher Modes of Operation
% Methods and Techniques
% NIST Special Publication 800-38A, 2001 Edition
% for details.

error(nargchk(4, 6, nargin));
validateattributes(s, {'struct'}, {});
validateattributes(oper, {'char'}, {});
validateattributes(mode, {'char'}, {});
validateattributes(input, {'numeric'}, {'real', 'vector', '>=', 0, '<', 256});
if (nargin >= 5)
    validateattributes(iv, {'numeric'}, {'real', 'vector', '>=', 0, '<', 256});
    if (length(iv) ~= 16)
        error('Length of ''iv'' must be 16.');
    end
end
if (nargin >= 6)
    validateattributes(sbit, {'numeric'}, {'real', 'scalar', '>=', 1, '<=', 128});
end

if (mod(length(input), 16))
    error('Length of ''input'' must be multiple of 16.');
end

switch lower(oper)
    case {'encrypt', 'enc', 'e'}
        oper = 0;
    case {'decrypt', 'dec', 'd'}
        oper = 1;
    otherwise
        error('Bad ''oper'' parameter.');
end

blocks = length(input)/16;
input = input(:);

switch lower(mode)

    case {'ecb'}
        % Electronic Codebook Mode
        % ------------------------
        output = zeros(1,length(input));
        idx = 1:16;
        for i = 1:blocks
            if (oper)
                % decrypt
                output(idx) = aesdecrypt(s,input(idx));
            else
                % encrypt
                output(idx) = aesencrypt(s,input(idx));
            end
            idx = idx + 16;
        end

    case {'cbc'}
        % Cipher Block Chaining Mode
        % --------------------------
        if (nargin < 5)
            error('Missing initialization vector ''iv''.');
        end
        output = zeros(1,length(input));
        ob = iv;
        idx = 1:16;
        for i = 1:blocks
            if (oper)
                % decrypt
                in = input(idx);
                output(idx) = bitxor(ob(:), aesdecrypt(s,in)');
                ob = in;
            else
                % encrypt
                ob = bitxor(ob(:), input(idx));
                ob = aesencrypt(s, ob);
                output(idx) = ob;
            end
            idx = idx + 16;
        end
        % store iv for block passing
        s.iv = ob;

    case {'cfb'}
        % Cipher Feedback Mode
        % --------------------
        % Special mode with bit manipulations
        % sbit = 1..128
        if (nargin < 6)
            error('Missing ''sbit'' parameter.');
        end
        % get number of bits
        bitlen = 8*length(input);
        % loop counter
        rounds = round(bitlen/sbit);
        % check 
        if (rem(bitlen, sbit))
            error('Message length in bits is not multiple of ''sbit''.');
        end
        % convert input to bitstream
        inputb = reshape(de2bi(input,8,2,'left-msb')',1,bitlen);
        % preset init. vector
        ib = iv;
        ibb = reshape(de2bi(ib,8,2,'left-msb')',1,128);
        % preset output binary stream
        outputb = zeros(size(inputb));
        for i = 1:rounds
            iba = aesencrypt(s, ib);
            % convert to bit, MSB first
            ibab = reshape(de2bi(iba,8,2,'left-msb')',1,128);
            % strip only sbit MSB bits
            % this goes to xor
            ibab = ibab(1:sbit);
            % strip bits from input
            inpb = inputb((i - 1)*sbit + (1:sbit));
            % make xor
            outb = bitxor(ibab, inpb);
            % write to output
            outputb((i - 1)*sbit + (1:sbit)) = outb;
            if (oper)
                % decrypt
                % prepare new iv - bit shift
                ibb = [ibb((1 + sbit):end) inpb];
            else
                % encrypt
                % prepare new iv - bit shift
                ibb = [ibb((1 + sbit):end) outb];
            end
            % back to byte ary
            ib = bi2de(vec2mat(ibb,8),'left-msb');
            % loop
        end
        output = bi2de(vec2mat(outputb,8),'left-msb');
        % store iv for block passing
        s.iv = ib;

    case {'ofb'}
        % Output Feedback Mode
        % --------------------
        if (nargin < 5)
            error('Missing initialization vector ''iv''.');
        end
        output = zeros(1,length(input));
        ib = iv;
        idx = 1:16;
        for i = 1:blocks
            % encrypt, decrypt
            ib = aesencrypt(s, ib);
            output(idx) = bitxor(ib(:), input(idx));
            idx = idx + 16;
        end
        % store iv for block passing
        s.iv = ib;

    case {'ctr'}
        % Counter Mode
        % ------------
        if (nargin < 5)
            iv = 1;
        end
        output = zeros(1,length(input));
        idx = 1:16;
        for i = (iv):(iv + blocks - 1)
            ib = AES_GET_COUNTER(i);
            ib = aesencrypt(s, ib);
            output(idx) = bitxor(ib(:), input(idx));
            idx = idx + 16;
        end
        s.iv = iv + blocks;

    otherwise
        error('Bad ''oper'' parameter.');
end
```

the aesencrypt function :

```
function [out] = aesencrypt(s, in)
% AESENCRYPT  Encrypt 16-bytes vector.
% Usage:            out = aesencrypt(s, in)
% s:                AES structure
% in:               input 16-bytes vector (plaintext)
% out:              output 16-bytes vector (ciphertext)
if (nargin ~= 2)
    error('Bad number of input arguments.');
end

validateattributes(s, {'struct'}, {});
validateattributes(in, {'numeric'}, {'real','uint8'});

% copy input to local
% 16 -> 4 x 4
state = reshape(in, 4, 4);

% Initial round
% AddRoundKey keyexp(1:4)
state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp(1:4, :))');

% Loop over (s.rounds - 1) rounds
for i = 1:(s.rounds - 1)
    % SubBytes - lookup table
    state = s.s_box(state + 1);
    % ShiftRows
    state = shift_rows(state, 0);
    % MixColumns
    state = mix_columns(state, s);
    % AddRoundKey keyexp(i*4 + (1:4))
    state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp((1:4) + 4*i, :))');
end

% Final round
% SubBytes - lookup table
state = s.s_box(state + 1);
% ShiftRows
state = shift_rows(state, 0);
% AddRoundKey keyexp(4*s.rounds + (1:4))
state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp(4*s.rounds + (1:4), :))');

% copy local to output
% 4 x 4 -> 16
out = reshape(state, 1, 16);
```

function aesinit:

```
function s = aesinit(key)
% AESINIT Generate structure with s-boxes, expanded key, etc.
% Usage:            s = aesinit([23 34 168 ... 39])
% key:              16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192), and 32 (AES-256)
%                   items array with bytes of key
% s:                AES structure for AES parameters and tables

% Stepan Matejka, 2011, matejka[at]feld.cvut.cz
% $Revision: 1.1.0 $  $Date: 2011/10/12 $

validateattributes(key,...
    {'numeric'},...
    {'real', 'vector', '>=', 0, '<=', 255});

key = key(:);
lengthkey = length(key);

switch (lengthkey)
    case 16
        rounds = 10;
    case 24
        rounds = 12;
    case 32
        rounds = 14;
    otherwise
        error('Only AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256 are supported.');
end

% fill s structure
s = {};
s.key = key;
s.bytes = lengthkey;
s.length = lengthkey * 8;
s.rounds = rounds;
% irreducible polynomial for multiplication in a finite field 0x11b
% bin2dec('100011011');
s.mod_pol = 283;

% s-box method 1 (slow)
% ---------------------

%     % multiplicative inverse table
%     % first is zero, calculate rest
%     inverse = zeros(1,256);
%     for i = 2:256
%         inverse(i) = find_inverse(i - 1, s.mod_pol);
%     end
%     
%     % generate s-box
%     s_box = zeros(1,256);
%     for i = 1:256
%         % affine transformation
%         s_box(i) = aff_trans(inverse(i));
%     end
%     s.s_box = s_box;
%     
%     % generate inverse s-box
%     inv_s_box(s_box(1:256) + 1) = (1:256) - 1;
%     s.inv_s_box = inv_s_box;

% s-box method 2 (faster)
% -----------------------

% first build logarithm lookup table and it's inverse
aes_logt = zeros(1,256);
aes_ilogt = zeros(1,256);
gen = 1;
for i = 0:255
    aes_logt(gen + 1) = i;
    aes_ilogt(i + 1) = gen;
    gen = poly_mult(gen, 3, s.mod_pol);
end
% store log tables
s.aes_logt = aes_logt;
s.aes_ilogt = aes_ilogt;
% build s-box and it's inverse
s_box = zeros(1,256);
loctable = [1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128];
for i = 0:255
    if (i == 0)
        inv = 0;
    else
        inv = aes_ilogt(255 - aes_logt(i + 1) + 1);
    end
    temp = 0;
    for bi = 0:7
        temp2 = sign(bitand(inv, loctable(bi + 1)));
        temp2 = temp2 + sign(bitand(inv, loctable(bi + 4 + 1)));
        temp2 = temp2 + sign(bitand(inv, loctable(bi + 5 + 1)));
        temp2 = temp2 + sign(bitand(inv, loctable(bi + 6 + 1)));
        temp2 = temp2 + sign(bitand(inv, loctable(bi + 7 + 1)));
        temp2 = temp2 + sign(bitand(99, loctable(bi + 1)));
        if (rem(temp2,2))
            temp = bitor(temp, loctable(bi + 1));
        end
    end
    s_box(i + 1) = temp;
end
inv_s_box(s_box(1:256) + 1) = (0:255);
% table correction (must be)
s_box(1 + 1) = 124;
inv_s_box(124 + 1) = 1;
inv_s_box(99 + 1) = 0;
s.s_box = s_box;
s.inv_s_box = inv_s_box;

% tables for fast MixColumns
mix_col2 = zeros(1,256);
mix_col3 = mix_col2;
mix_col9 = mix_col2;
mix_col11 = mix_col2;
mix_col13 = mix_col2;
mix_col14 = mix_col2;
for i = 1:256
    mix_col2(i) = poly_mult(2, i - 1, s.mod_pol);
    mix_col3(i) = poly_mult(3, i - 1, s.mod_pol);
    mix_col9(i) = poly_mult(9, i - 1, s.mod_pol);
    mix_col11(i) = poly_mult(11, i - 1, s.mod_pol);
    mix_col13(i) = poly_mult(13, i - 1, s.mod_pol);
    mix_col14(i) = poly_mult(14, i - 1, s.mod_pol);
end
s.mix_col2 = mix_col2;
s.mix_col3 = mix_col3;
s.mix_col9 = mix_col9;
s.mix_col11 = mix_col11;
s.mix_col13 = mix_col13;
s.mix_col14 = mix_col14;

% expanded key
s.keyexp = key_expansion(s.key, s.s_box, s.rounds, s.mod_pol, s.aes_logt, s.aes_ilogt);

% poly & invpoly
s.poly_mat = [...
    2 3 1 1;...
    1 2 3 1;...
    1 1 2 3;...
    3 1 1 2];

s.inv_poly_mat =[...
    14 11 13  9;...
    9  14 11 13;...
    13  9 14 11;...
    11 13  9 14];

% end of aesinit.m
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

function p = poly_mult(a, b, mod_pol)
% Multiplication in a finite field
% For loop multiplication - slower than log/ilog tables
% but must be used for log/ilog tables generation

p = 0;
for counter = 1 : 8
    if (rem(b, 2))
        p = bitxor(p, a);
        b = (b - 1)/2;
    else
        b = b/2;
    end
    a = 2*a;
    if (a > 255)
        a = bitxor(a, mod_pol);
    end
end

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function inv = find_inverse(in, mod_pol)
% Multiplicative inverse for an element a of a finite field
% very bad calculate & test method
% Not used in faster version

% loop over all possible bytes
for inv = 1 : 255
    % calculate polynomial multiplication and test to be 1
    if (1 == poly_mult(in, inv, mod_pol))
        % we find it
        break
    end
end
inv = 0;

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function out = aff_trans(in)
% Affine transformation over GF(2^8)
% Not used for faster s-box generation

% modulo polynomial for multiplication in a finite field
% bin2dec('100000001');
mod_pol = 257;

% multiplication polynomial
% bin2dec('00011111');
mult_pol = 31;

% addition polynomial
% bin2dec('01100011');
add_pol = 99;

% polynomial multiplication
temp = poly_mult(in, mult_pol, mod_pol);

% xor with addition polynomial
out = bitxor(temp, add_pol);

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function expkey = key_expansion(key, s_box, rounds, mod_pol, aes_logt, aes_ilogt)
% Expansion of key

% This is old version for AES-128 (192?, 256? not tested):
% rcon = ones(1,rounds);
% for i = 2:rounds
%     rcon(i) = poly_mult(rcon(i - 1), 2, mod_pol);
% end
% % fill bytes 2, 3, and 4 by 0
% rcon = [rcon(:), zeros(rounds, 3)];
% 
% kcol = length(key)/4;
% expkey = (reshape(key, kcol, 4))';
% for i = (kcol + 1):(4*rounds + 4)
%     % copy the previous row of the expanded key into a buffer
%     temp = expkey(i - 1, :);
%     % each fourth row
%     if (mod(i, 4) == 1)
%         % shift temp
%         temp = temp([2 3 4 1]);
%         % s-box transform
%         temp = s_box(temp + 1);
%         % compute the current round constant
%         r = rcon((i - 1)/4, :);
%         % xor
%         temp = bitxor(temp, r);
%     else
%         if ((kcol > 6) && (mod(i, kcol) == 0))
%             temp = s_box(temp);
%         end
%     end
%     % generate new row of the expanded key
%     expkey(i, :) = bitxor(expkey(i - 4, :), temp);
% end

% This is new faster version for all AES:
rcon = 1;
kcol = length(key)/4;
expkey = (reshape(key,4,kcol))';
% traverse for all rounds
for i = kcol:(4*(rounds + 1) - 1)
    % copy the previous row of the expanded key into a buffer
    temp = expkey(i, :);
    % each kcol row
    if (mod(i, kcol) == 0)
        % rotate word
        temp = temp([2 3 4 1]);
        % s-box transform
        temp = s_box(temp + 1);
        % xor
        temp(1) = bitxor(temp(1), rcon);
        % new rcon
        % 1. classic poly_mult
        % rcon = poly_mult(rcon, 2, mod_pol);
        % 2. or faster version with log/ilog tables
        % note rcon is never zero here
        % rcon = aes_ilogt(mod((aes_logt(rcon + 1) + aes_logt(2 + 1)), 255) + 1);
        rcon = aes_ilogt(mod((aes_logt(rcon + 1) + 25), 255) + 1);
    else
        if ((kcol > 6) && (mod(i, kcol) == 4))
            temp = s_box(temp + 1);
        end
    end
    % generate new row of the expanded key
    expkey(i + 1, :) = bitxor(expkey(i - kcol + 1, :), temp);
end
```

Comment: Not giving people a lot of chance to help you here, you're asking for help to adapt something you found on the web, without mentioning what you found?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. As u know this algorithm is constituted by 4 steps

Comment: i found the program of these steps but its just for encrypting a plain text. input is 16 byte vector, and I'm asking what should I change in this program to adapt it to my project

Comment: Again, without any reference to the program you found.

Comment: Ok I will copy what a found.

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't copy but there is the link when I found the whole code

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is clear now. I voted to reopen the question. In general when using external code it is a good idea to also link where you got it from and mentioned how you call it.

Comment: @excaza have a look now

Comment: @rohit5k2 have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited to 128 bits because you tried to encrypt using `aesencrypt`, [one of the low level functions which work on 4x4 blocks](https://github.com/tellezhector/cryptography/blob/master/aes/Readme.m). If you instead use the [`aes`](https://github.com/tellezhector/cryptography/blob/master/aes/aes.m) function you can encode any "byte-vector with length multiple of 16". It will repeatedly call `aesenrypt` for you until all 4x4 blocks are processed.

Comment: i see that @Daniel thanks. and how about implement AES to crypt a JPEG image or other format!!

Comment: @Joe.Ou: The first two lines from CTS-Link's answer explains how to read a file into a byte array. You don't need anything specific for JPEG image, treat every file the same way.

Comment: Hey again @Daniel. I have a problem with the length it most be multiple of 16. So I have to pad !! How could I do it in the encryption and also the decryption program. thanks

Comment: Yes you have to pad, what is the problem doing it?

Comment: The problem is i will work on different images, each one have its length (that impossible to know it because my goal is to realize a program that work for all kind of image that matlab could read) . In all the cases the length must be multiple of 16. @Daniel

Comment: Simple answer, store the number of inserted bytes as well. A code could for example be: First byte the number of padding bytes (`uint8`/one byte is enough), then some padding bytes and finally your data. If you fail to implement this, I recommend to ask a new question which also contains your code.